# integer input validation python

Tags: python, loops

can't seem to get this loop to work, it keeps looping back to the Binary Number Input. I'd like it to loop back to the menu selection. Sorry for the noob question I'm new to python and programming.

```
import sys
loop = 0
menu_Select = 0
for menu_Select in range(1,100):
    #Display user options to the screen
    print('*** Menu ***')
    print('1. Convert to binary')

    userMenu = input('What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? ')
    if userMenu != '1' and userMenu != '2' and userMenu != '3' and userMenu != '4':
        print("Please enter either 1, 2, 3, or 4.")

    elif userMenu == '4':
        print('Goodbye.')
        sys.exit(0)

    elif userMenu == '1':
        #Decimal to Binary convertion code
        print('\n')
        while loop < 1:
            while True:
                try:
                    user_Number = (int(input('Please enter number: ')))
                except ValueError:
                    print('wrong')
                else:
                    binary_num = []

                    while (user_Number > 0):
                        if user_Number % 2 != 0:
                            binary_num.append(1)
                        elif user_Number % 2 == 0:
                            binary_num.append(0)
                        user_Number = user_Number // 2
                    binary_num.reverse()
                    binary_display = ''.join(str(k) for k in binary_num)
                    print('Binary number: ',binary_display)
            loop += 1
```

Comment: When do you expect your `while True:` loop to end?

Comment: After the binary number is displayed

Comment: I'm not allowed to use a break statement

Comment: Something different: You should avoid things like `if userMenu != '1' and userMenu != '2' and userMenu != '3' and userMenu != '4':` to check for undefined options. Either do `if int(userMenu) in range(1,5):`, or do the corresponding `print` command in an `else` statement after the behavior for valid options is defined.

Comment: You need a `break` to exit this loop. Why is that loop in the code anyway?

Comment: I have changed the code @Matthias removed the while loop > 1, and placed a break after the last print statement. It works but I'm not allowed to use break. I'm using the loop to validate for number input

Comment: You can introduce a boolean variable, like `done = False`, before the `while True` loop, and change this to `while not done`. Then set `done` to `True` after the binary number was printed.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you need `while loop < 1` and `while True`. Did you just copy and paste some code without knowing what it does? get rid of the `while` loops and you'll need no `break`.

Comment: @Matthias I guess a while loop is used to repeatedly ask for a number in case non-integer inputs are given. However, i also don't see the point of two of them.

Comment: I've just looked at lots of similar examples and tried to come up with solution. I have now removed the `while True`. However it loops back to the menu, instead of asking for another number. I have also removed the other while loop, which I've realized is not necessary.

Comment: @Bastian35022, adding `done = False` and `while not done:` has worked. The input validation works and it asks for the input again if it is not an integer. After the output binary code comes out it loops back to the Menu. Thanks heaps @Matthias @Bastian35022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using input() will actually convert what the user types into an int if it can. So take a look at what happens:

```
>>> input("= ")
= 12
12
```

That returns 12, not '12'. For input to give me '12' I need to manually wrap it in quotes.

```
>>> input("= ")
= '12'
'12'
```

Instead, use raw_input() to get Python to read anything the user types as a string.

```
>>> raw_input("= ")
= 12
'12'
```

Also, as others have mentioned you're using the while loops wrong. If you want to keep asking the user for input until you get a valid number, it's better to wrap a smaller amount of code with the relevant condition.

ie. Have the loop only run while there isn't a valid number, and have it only contain the lines where the input is happening.

```
        user_Number = None
        while user_Number is None:
            try:
                user_Number = (int(raw_input('Please enter number: ')))
            except ValueError:
                print('wrong')
        binary_num = []

        while (user_Number > 0):
            if user_Number % 2 != 0:
                binary_num.append(1)
            elif user_Number % 2 == 0:
                binary_num.append(0)
                user_Number = user_Number // 2
        binary_num.reverse()
        binary_display = ''.join(str(k) for k in binary_num)
        print('Binary number: ',binary_display)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a boolean variable `done = False`, before the while True loop, and change this loop to `while not done`. Then set `done` to `True` after the binary number was printed.

```
elif userMenu == '1':
    #Decimal to Binary convertion code
    print('\n')
    done = False
    while not done:
        try:
            user_Number = (int(input('Please enter number: ')))
        except ValueError:
            print('wrong')
        else:
            binary_num = []
            while (user_Number > 0):
                if user_Number % 2 != 0:
                    binary_num.append(1)
                elif user_Number % 2 == 0:
                    binary_num.append(0)
                user_Number = user_Number // 2
            binary_num.reverse()
            binary_display = ''.join(str(k) for k in binary_num)
            print('Binary number: ',binary_display)
            done = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if userMenu != '1' and userMenu != '2' and userMenu != '3' and userMenu != '4':
```

To:

```
if userMenu != 1 and userMenu != 2 and userMenu != 3 and userMenu != 4:
```

And also update your if statements to see if they are int's rather than strings. This will work on python 2.7, not sure about python 3.

Comment: The code looks like Python 3 so your answer is wrong. If you read the question carefully you'll see that this is not the problem.

Comment: Gotcha. I put his code into mine which is running 2.7 and ran it, it was looping on the first question and never reaching the if statements. But I see now that he needs to break out of his `while True` loop too.